# Made quick script to search bash history - How can I make it more robust?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

I got tired of typing

```
grep "{search term}" ~/.bash_history
```

to search terms in my previous bash history. so i just wrote out this python script and put it in /usr/bin/local so I only have to type

```
hist {search term}
```

And I get a list of all lines in the bash history that used that search term.

Here's the script:

```
#hist
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call("grep " + sys.argv[1] + " ~/.bash_history", shell=True)
```

It works great for the most part. However I noticed that if I type

```
hist "-L"
```

I get the below errors:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/hist", line 6, in <module>
subprocess.call("grep " + sys.argv[1] + " ~/.bash_history", shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1392, in wait
pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 476, in _eintr_retry_call
return func(*args)
```

How can I fix this aspect, and what are some best practices for these kinds of scripts in general?

Comment: Why not [CTRL+R?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73498/how-to-cycle-through-reverse-i-search-in-bash)

Comment: I didn't know that CTRL+R was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a more robust command line program with Python, consider using a library for handling arguments. As of writing this answer, the most popular are [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), [Docopt](http://docopt.org/), and [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/). They all have their own flavor, and it's up to you and your use-case which one is the best fit.

[This article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/comparing-python-command-line-parsing-libraries-argparse-docopt-click/) does a fairly good comparison of the basic usage of all three.

Comment: Those look promising. Thanks for the links!

Answer (score 1):

Solutions:

@jDo:
Use CTRL+R for searching bash history

@Julien:
Use Argparse, Docopt or Click for robust python command-line parsing

Thanks everyone.